# I'm a beginner. how apply a code to all files and save new txt?

Tags: r, loops, write.table

I have this code for smoothing a spectra!

```
list_tot <- list.files(path = ".", pattern="*.txt")
num <- as.integer(length(list_tot))


library(data.table)
DT_final_tot <- fread(file = list_tot[1])
setnames(DT_final_tot, c("Raman shift (cm-1)", list_tot[1]))

x <-DT_final_tot[[1]]
y <-DT_final_tot[[2]]

smooth_spectra <- smooth.spline(x,y, spar = NULL) 
plot(x,y, type = "l", main="raw spectra", col="green") 
lines(smooth_spectra,type = "l") 
plot(smooth_spectra,type = "l", main="smooth spectra ")
```

I've applied the code at the first file of the folder! how can I apply it to all the files and how can I save the smoothed spectra as txt. file?

Comment: What language is this?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
list_tot <- list.files(path = ".", pattern="*.txt")
num <- as.integer(length(list_tot))

for(fname in list_tot) {
  DT_final_tot <- fread(file = fname)
  setnames(DT_final_tot, c("Raman shift (cm-1)", fname))

  x <-DT_final_tot[[1]]
  y <-DT_final_tot[[2]]

  smooth_spectra <- smooth.spline(x,y, spar = NULL) 
  plot(x,y, type = "l", main="raw spectra", col="green") 
  lines(smooth_spectra,type = "l") 
  plot(smooth_spectra,type = "l", main="smooth spectra ")

  dump(c("smooth_spectra"), file=paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(fname), "_smoothed", ".csv"))
}
```

You should introduce the `for` loop to iterate over the `list_tot`. It will save the `smooth_spectra` in the file, with the name same as input file, with `_smoothed` prefix and `.csv` extension.

Comment: thank you. I changed write.csv in write.table and .csv in .txt because i need txt. Anyway i have an error: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""smooth.spline"" to a data.frame

Comment: @AlbertoCaracciolo How do you want to store it? I have updated the answer.

Comment: I like to store it in a new folder (called "smoothed" for example), in the same directory!